# Abort the execution of external managed code(plugin)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

In our application, we have a plugin system that takes compilers in the form of plugins, written specifically for our software. The plugins are assembly files, imported using MEF. The user is then able to select a compiler, and use it to compile a piece of source code.

A problem arises, if there is a faulty plugin added to the system. Upon execution, it could potentially hang the whole service, requiring a complete restart. I am looking for a way to stop the execution of a compiler after a certain timeout, without the need for TaskCancellation handling in the plugins, since you can never be sure that it will implemented properly, if at all. Of course, I also need to be sure that proper clean up is done after aborting, since failure to do that, could also crash or slow down the system.

I do understand that forcefully terminating managed code could potentially lead to a lot of problems and that is the reason I am asking for a good way to do it.

Comment: Run your plugins in separate appdomain.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Would you mind giving me an example on how to accomplish that with MEF?

Comment: There is no good way short of running such code in separate process...